# IOS push notification do not reach the device from the MDM server

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I am working on mobile device management system and my push notification isnt working. My Code is

```
//$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'PushCert.pem';

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'my-device-token'; //I have replaced my actual token here

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $error $errorString" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I got the message like "Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered." but notification doesnt came on the IPhone device. What else should I check and what can be the solution? I also checked the Iphone logs into the configuration utility but no logs are seen when I run my script.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did u get any success in that

Comment: Certificate file is generated for production or development ?